# What is the order of AbstractModule class binding when used with Guice?

Tags: scala, guice

The question is probably more understandable with an example.

I am using `Guice` to create injector:

```
  val injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module)
```

with the following Module class:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    val instance = aCallToGetAnInstance()
    bind(classOf[DummyClass]).toInstance(instance)
    bind(classOf[DummyClass2]).asEagerSingleton()
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  def provideDummyService: DummyService = {
    DummyService.standard.build()
  }

}
```

Which of these 3 bound classes would be bound first?

This question seems to make sense if one of the following calls inject one of the other class.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Probably there is an injection framework being used. which one?

Comment: Yes, `guice`, I updated the question thanks for your feedback ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what the Injection framework does for you.

As long you don't have **any cycle in your code** `guice` can resolve it.

At startup all the bindings are verified (it complains for example if you have cycles). The instantiation however is when needed (lazy) - the exception is `eager singleton`.

Just comment if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Hi @pme, thanks for your answer. So, every class instances is lazily bound?

Comment: I adjusted my answer

Comment: And most of the cycles can be resolved if you use the interface - implementation abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Having `@Provides` and `@Singleton` on the `provideDummyService` method is enough. Guice will find methods annotated with `@Provides` and do the wiring for you. It does this using Java Reflection. There is no need to add anything in the configure() method.

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods

Comment: Oh I see you updated the question. As for "which one will be bound first", my take is that: 1) instance (DummyClass), 2) DummyClass2 3) DummyService.

This is so because 3 is going to be a lazy provider, 2 is going to be an eager singleton (and it will be created there) and 1) is first because you called it first.